# If a character uses Relentless Endurance with Life Transference, how much does it heal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits

The spell Life Transference (from Xanathar's Guide to Everything) states that you can heal a creature equal to twice the damage you self-inflict by the spell.

If a half-orc uses this spell while on very low health and activates its Relentless Endurance racial ability, will it heal based on the total damage or only the initial HP - 1?

Is there any difference if I don't use my Relentless Endurance?

Comment: actually, *Relentless Endurance* is irrelevant to this question. The question would also come up if you *don't* have the ability, but take more damage than you have hit points remaining.

Comment: @PixelMaster I realized this after I made the question. Was thinking about posting a separate question with the general case. While I think the ruling would be the same, there might be something in overlooking. I added to this question. Not sure if it is different enough for a whole new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can use the ability.

*Relentless Endurance* states:

> ***Relentless Endurance***. When you are reduced to
>   0 hit points but not killed outright, you can drop to 1 hit
>   point instead. You can’t use this feature again until you
>   finish a long rest.

Since the spell says nothing about killing you outright if this damage reduces you to 0 hit points, and there's no mention of the source of the damage, yes, the ability would activate when you take damage from *Life Transference*, which states the following:

> You sacrifice some of your health to mend another creature’s injuries. You take 4d8 necrotic damage, and one
>   creature of your choice that you can see within range regains
>   a number of hit points equal to twice the necrotic
>   damage you take.

There is no mention of something along the lines of "this damage can't be reduced in any way", as the *Wish* spell does:

> ***Wish.*** [...] The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect
>   other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After
>   enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until
>   you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage
>   per level of that spell. This damage can’t be reduced or
>   prevented in any way.

Therefore, since spells in D&D 5e only do what they say, yes, you can use the spell in this way (at least according to RAW - your DM might decide otherwise).

---

### The creature heals whatever you rolled on your 4d8 (or more, depending on the spell level).

To answer your question about how much healing is applied, this is what happens:

You cast the spell -> you take 4d8 damage + the creature of your choice within range regains the exact same amount -> you are reduced to 0 HP -> your ability activates, so you have 1 HP instead.

There's a difference between the amount damage you take, and the amount that your hit points are effectively reduced.
On page 196 of the PHB, the section *Hit Points* states:

> A creature’s current hit points (usually just called hit
>   points) can be any number from the creature’s hit point
>   maximum down to 0.

Therefore, if you're e.g. at 10HP, cast the spell and roll 17 damage on the 4d8, you would be at -7 HP. However, your hit points can only be between 0 and max, so you drop to 0 instead - **but you still took 17 damage**.

The difference between damage taken and HP lost is further supported by the section about instant death, PHB p. 197:

> Instant Death
>   Massive damage can kill you instantly. When damage
>   reduces you to 0 hit points and there is damage
>   remaining, you die if the remaining damage equals
>   or exceeds your hit point maximum.

Comment: My question is with regard to how much you would heal not whether you could use the trait.

Comment: my bad, I misread. You might want to edit your title, it's misleading.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: There's a clarifying quote in the section on dropping to zero hit points that I noticed: "If she takes 18 damage from an attack, she is reduced to 0 hit points, but 12 damage remains." Adding this would make it more obvious that the intent is you still take the damage